# Двойные запросы (401->200) при использовании Kerbersos аутентификации

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, аутентификация, kerberos

Настроена Kerberos аутентификация в IE все работает.Crhome и Firefox не отправляют Authorization заголовок. И постоянно получают 401 и только после этого отправляют запрос с нужным заголовком. вот лог.

```
Firefox 69
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /request.php HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /request.php HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /css/bootstrap.min4.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /css/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /css/index.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /css/all.min.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /css/index.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /css/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /css/bootstrap.min4.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui.datepicker-ru.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui-timepicker-ru.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    401 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui.datepicker-ru.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui-timepicker-ru.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:11    200 Firefox GET /js/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:12    401 Firefox GET /img/domain_0.png HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:12    200 Firefox GET /img/domain_0.png HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:09:28:12    401 Firefox GET /img/td-bkh.ico HTTP/1.1
```

Начало стандартное - запрос GET /request.php без авторизации, сервер отдает 401 с требованием авторизоваться, браузер повторяет запрос с авторизацией, сервер отвечает 200
Потом Firefox посылает запросы к другим элементам без Authorization в Header'e. На все запросы получает 401. Перепосылает с Authorization, получает 200.
В итоге имеем в 2 раза больше запросов.

```
Chrome 77
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    401 Chrome  GET /request.php HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    200 Chrome  GET /request.php HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    401 Chrome  GET /css/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    401 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    401 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    401 Chrome  GET /css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    401 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui-timepicker-ru.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    401 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui.datepicker-ru.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    200 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    401 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    200 Chrome  GET /css/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    200 Chrome  GET /css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    200 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui.datepicker-ru.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    200 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui-timepicker-ru.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    200 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js HTTP/1.1
10.1.2.3    16/Oct/2019:11:50:15    200 Chrome  GET /js/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Данный рецепт пробовали [настройка аутентификации Kerberos](http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2018/01/22/nastrojka-kerberos-autentifikacii-v-razlichnyx-brauzerax/) ?

Comment: Да, не помогло.

Comment: Возможно поможет добавления ресурса в белый список [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Integrated_authentication)